# Dynamically pass iframe url parameters to parent URL

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I'm new with iframe interactions with parent, so let me explain the issue I'm facing in simple terms:

I have a site with an iframe. How can I use JavaScript or jQuery code to dynamically change my parent URL depending on what the user clicks in the iframe?

For example, if my parent URL is `parent.com?page=1&currency=eur`  then my iframe will automatically be `iframe.com?page=1&currency=eur`, but the user can click another link inside the iframe. If the user clicks on a link and the iframe src changes to `iframe.com?page=another_page`, I want the parent URL to dynamically change to `parent.com/page=another_page` or `parent.com#page=another_page`. In other words, I pass all iframe URL parameters to parent.

Can anyone help me with this?

I have full control over parent window and can add some code to child as well but they're not on the same domain.

Thanks

Comment: From the page you keep the `<iframe></iframe>`,  `const iframeWindow = document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow;` gets the `window` of the other page. From the page that contains the content `const parentWindow = parent;`, gets the parent `window`. Both of those variables are `window` Objects now, so `parentWindow.location` can get and set the `location`. The problem with assigning GET URLs, is that your page will reload, therefore `sessionStorage`, or `localStorage`, or hashtags are probably a better solution.

Comment: To expand on what @StackSlave is telling you , using [parent.history.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) you **can** change the parent url without a reload.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to achieve interaction between parent-iframe/child window across 2 different domains.

In your case, since your child is modifying your parent, you should set up a listener on your parent page like so

```
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  if (event.origin !== "http://thisisyourchilddomain.com") // You must check for the sender's origin or your website could be exploited !!
    return;

  // do something
}, false);
```

And in your child page, you would call the method *window.postMessage*

```
parent.postMessage("hello there parent! please perform a redirect with the following params...", "http://thisisyourchilddomain.com");
```

Note that parent is a global here that you can access from your child. Also, you can pass an object to the first parameter of postMessage({key:value}, ..)

Examples were taken and modified from the link to window.postMessage (mozilla).